# Is it possible to set a link speed for a port?

Tags: dpdk

I would like to know if it's possible to start links with link speeds of my choosing. I believe I saw a topic not unlike this one on the website before, but I cannot find it anymore.

To my understanding, one would need to set the "link_speeds" field in the rte_eth_conf struct to some value that isn't RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_AUTONEG, but regardless of what I choose, checking the link in rte_eth_link_get always gives me 1000M and autoneg.
Now, I also tried to look into the code from rte_eth_dev_configure to see how it does what it does, but it doesn't seem to take the link_speeds parameter into account. Keep in mind, I'm rather new to all this.
Anyway, I have yet to attempt this outside of my VM, so perhaps it's due to the e1000 driver but if I had to guess it is something else entirely.
Also, I did see on some website that interfaces had forced speeds and duplex (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/forced-speedduplex-interface-settings-not-working-xgs-firmware-53), though the post dates a bit so I'm still hoping things are different now.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with setting `link_speeds` in `rte_eth_conf` *before* it's used in the call to `rte_eth_dev_configure`.  Note that the [documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__eth__conf.html#ad8c15e528dccff643adf7fc96fec6473) says you must set the `RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_FIXED` bit of `link_speeds` in *addition* to setting one link speed.  Perhaps that's the step you're missing?

The `link_speeds` field is used in the drivers/net/* files and not in `rte_eth_dev_configure` directly, because it is a hardware-specific request.  For instance, if I look at [drivers/net/e1000/igb_ethdev.c](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/e1000/igb_ethdev.c#L1310), I see usage of `link_speeds` in `eth_igb_start`

To investigate speed capabilities of a device, you'd make a call to `rte_eth_dev_info_get`, e.g. `rte_eth_dev_info_get(port_id, &dev_info)` and look at `dev_info.speed_capa`.

[`test-pmd`](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/app/test-pmd/config.c#L577) prints them nicely:

```c
static void
device_infos_display_speeds(uint32_t speed_capa)
{
        printf("\n\tDevice speed capability:");
        if (speed_capa == RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_AUTONEG)
                printf(" Autonegotiate (all speeds)");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_FIXED)
                printf(" Disable autonegotiate (fixed speed)  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_10M_HD)
                printf(" 10 Mbps half-duplex  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_10M)
                printf(" 10 Mbps full-duplex  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_100M_HD)
                printf(" 100 Mbps half-duplex  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_100M)
                printf(" 100 Mbps full-duplex  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_1G)
                printf(" 1 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_2_5G)
                printf(" 2.5 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_5G)
                printf(" 5 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_10G)
                printf(" 10 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_20G)
                printf(" 20 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_25G)
                printf(" 25 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_40G)
                printf(" 40 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_50G)
                printf(" 50 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_56G)
                printf(" 56 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_100G)
                printf(" 100 Gbps  ");
        if (speed_capa & RTE_ETH_LINK_SPEED_200G)
                printf(" 200 Gbps  ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I did manage to get a "fixed" speed, but it's still 1000Mbs. My e1000 device indicates a speed_capa of 62, which I suppose means it covers 10M HD to 1G, but I thought setting link_speeds to like, 5 for example should make it 10M, but it clearly doesn't. Am I missing something still ? Sorry if it's a simple matter

Comment: Apparently there are many e1000's.  If you do an lspci you might be able to better identify which one you have based on this [list](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/e1000/base/e1000_hw.h#L14).  Using that knowledge, you can check the various `setup_link` functions in drivers/net/e1000/base to see if one of them may be overriding your request.  Before doing that, I would try to re-bind to the standard driver and configure the ethernet device in Linux using ethtool, e.g. `ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off` (substitute your device name for eth0).

Comment: I see. My virtual nic is the 82540, and it does indeed seem like it does its own link setup, disregarding user settings. Unlike, say, the 82543 one for example. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: One of the "harsh" realities is that, whereas the DPDK API is very broad, most cards only implement a relatively small portion of it.